# How do I get bmpsize working with htlatex?

Tags: graphics, tex4ht, htlatex

I have the following `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tex4ht}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[natwidth=1594.7871bp,natheight=1147.85222bp,width=0.65\textwidth,height=0.65\textwidth]{torus-lores-bw.png}
\end{document}
```

Running `latex` gives:

```
D:\Documents\GitHub\book\foo>latex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\foo\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\bmpsize.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\dvips.def"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\bmpsize-base.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-basic.sty"
`Basic Fixed Point Arithmetic',  Version 1.2d (C) Michael Mehlich             )
 ("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-snap.sty"
`Fixed Point Snap Off',          Version 1.0a (C) Michael Mehlich             )
) ("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\bmpsize-dvips.def"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) ("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty"
--- needs --- tex4ht test ---
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\foo\test.tmp)
l.1437 --- TeX4ht warning --- No file test.xref ---
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\graphics.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\dvips.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\graphicx.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
No file test.aux.

LaTeX Warning: File `torus-lores-bw.png' not found on input line 6.

<torus-lores-bw.png>
! Undefined control sequence.
\b:graphics ...ght !*?: " }\egroup \fi \fi \E:IMG
                                                  \HCode {<!--tex4ht:graphic...
l.6 ...,height=0.65\textwidth]{torus-lores-bw.png}

?
```

If I remove the `tex4ht` package, or the `bmpsize` package, everything works fine.  (Well, it works fine if there's a .png file with the right name available.  But you get this error even if there isn't.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that both `tex4ht` and `bmpsize` tries to redefine `\includegraphics` and these redefinition clash. There are two options:

1. make tex4ht configuration file for `bmpsize` package and resolve conflicts here
2. edit your document to not include `bmpsize` with `tex4ht`

option 2 is much easier to do, option 1 would require someone with knowledge of `graphicx`, `bmpsize` and `tex4ht` packages. if you only include `png` images, which are supported by `tex4ht`, I don't think you need `bmpsize` package anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{}
{\usepackage{bmpsize}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[natwidth=1594.7871bp,natheight=1147.85222bp,width=0.65\textwidth,height=0.65\textwidth]{torus-lores-bw.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I don't specify natwidth and natheight, then `htlatex` gives me errors about not being able to compute the bounding boxes of .png files.  I want to use bmpsize to autocalculate such sizes.